# text based browser 64 bit Windows 7

Tags: browser, open-source, windows-7

Can anyone tell me if there is any text based browser for 64bit text based browser. Lynx browser supports only 32 bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run 32-bit programs, including Lynx, on 64-bit operating systems.

[Here](http://www.vordweb.co.uk/standards/download_lynx.htm) are instructions.

Comment: i tried its not working. Do i need to do something special

Comment: Why? What happened?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing Cygwin and the installing Lynx or w3m?

Answer (score 1):

Dillo? - http://www.dillo.org/download.html

Firefox + vimperator extension?

Comment: Firefox + Vimperator has improved my productivity 100%